# Rails: Dropdown menu to select results per page with will paginate

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pagination

I currently have a page on my rail site that will show, by default, 25 results per page using will_paginate. I would, however, like to have a dropdown menu that allows the user to select the number of results shown from a predetermined list of values. I looked at the answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281093/rails-showing-10-or-20-or-50-results-per-page-with-will-paginate-how-to) but the problem I have with the top solution is that I also have a search field in the same page and changing the number of results per page thus removes the search parameter if there is one.

I was wondering if there was any way for me to get around this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean the search parameter is removed? Can you not change the search parameter based upon which select value is chosen?

Comment: So in my page I have a search field where you can search the paginated results, so the url becomes something like www.-----./----/?search=--- but using the given answer in that page if you select a different value for results per page the url will become www.------./----/?per_page=--- so the table will no longer be filtered by the search param.

Comment: So I was wondering if there was a way for me to allow both parameters to be changed simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The select box proved to be troublesome but i found a different way to do the same functionality.

So by using anchor tags and grabbing the search params when building the path it preserves the search criteria as well as any new per_page value.
so 5 and 10 page links would look like this

```
<%= Link_to "5", current_path(:per_page =>5,:search => params[:search])%>
<%= Link_to "10", current_path(:per_page =>10,:search => params[:search])%>
```

and the URL in the href will look like this: `whatever.com/current?per_page=10&search=DevOps` changing with whatever search term is provided.

Be sure to add the per_page value to the controller as well

`per_page = params[:per_page]
 @items = Item.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: per_page)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your view -

```
<%= form_tag xyz_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([10, 20, 50, 100], params[:per_page]) %>
  <%= button_tag :submit %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller -

```
unless params[:per_page].present?
  params[:per_page] = 20 #default
end
if params[:search].present?
  ModelName.where(query: params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:per_page])
else
  ModelName.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:per_page])
end
```